# Illustrator: Crop everything outside of rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to delete the white part that is outside of the blue rectangle (I've placed a black rectangle behind just to show what's there.

[image]

Comment: Many questions, such as this, can be answered by reviewing the [basic operations within Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustration-techniques.html).

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Here's some more links to help. Look up [how to use clipping masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html), or the [how to use the Shape Builder tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html)

Comment: @muchlikearizona As Scott mentioned this is basic functionality of Illustrator. Read up on "clipping masks".